# iPhoneX: how to hide bottom inset for UIWindow?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow, iphone-x

I have 2 UIWindows in my app. Top one for the app and bottom for the banner. It works great on all devices except iPhoneX.

I need to remove bottom inset for app's UIWindow.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoCNB.jpg

Comment: Do not misuse windows like this. Your app should have only one window.

Comment: @matt, the bottom banner should be always on the screen for the app. So, it's the only option.

Comment: Not so. There is a way to do this with an ordinary subview of the window.

Comment: i guess the solution is to increate height of app UIWindow to iphoneX bottom inset. i will try

Comment: @matt and it will be visible on pushes, modal view presentation?